# Javascript scoping, this, prototype

Tags: javascript

I have this function, which defines a new type called store.  I decorate/modify app.set as shown below, so that it prints to console.log.

But after that, when trying to call app.set (set b below), I get TypeError: Cannot set property 'b' of undefined.  I'm assuming it's something to do with not being able to find 'this'.  What is wrong with this code?

```
function store(obj){
    this.data = obj || {};
}

store.prototype.get = function(k){
    return this.data[k];
}

store.prototype.set = function(k, v){
    return this.data[k] = v;
}

app = new store();

app.set('a',1);

app.set = (function(old){
    return function(k, v){
       console.log(k + ' yea!');
       old(k, v);
    }
})(app.set)

app.set('b',2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `old` `app.set` has no reference to `app` anymore. You need to `call` or `apply` it to  the correct instance:

```
old.call(app, k, v);
```

To see the difference more clearly, a few examples:

```
var obj = {
  name: "Heisenberg",

  sayMyName: function() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
};

obj.sayMyName(); // Prints "Heisenberg"

var say = obj.sayMyName;
say(); // Prints ""

say.call({ name: "Lucy" }); // Prints "Lucy"
```